Changing Wallpaper Automatically
When I had Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC I used the following script to change the wallpaper at boot time via cron
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/alex/Wallpapers

DAY=`date +%j`

TYPE=".jpg"

BKG=$DAY$TYPE

cp $BKG /home/alex/Pictures/Wallpapers/Wallpaper
/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file:///home/alex/Pictures/Wallpapers/Wallpaper"

This worked fine.
Updating to Ubuntu 22.0.4 caused the script to fail at reboot, but I could still run it manually when I logged on
Now updated to 24.0.4 and it does not work at all
I am assured by at least 6 'helpful' websites that the syntax and command is correct, but it does not work
The 24.0.4 is not an updated install, due to a hard drive failure it is a clean install.
Any help / explanation will be welcome

The script could use some improvements but do you have dark mode actually enabled? Otherwise the command should be /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/alex/Pictures/Wallpapers/Wallpaper"

Dark mode is enabled

How are you running the script? Via "Startup Applications" / ~/.config/autostart? If so can you show the actual "Startup Applications" command / ~/.config/autostart .desktop file? is the script exectuable?

Just had a thought from your answer (kos) - switched out of dark mode, changed the script for 'normal' mode and it works. Switch to dark mode, change script as required - does not work. Guess I'll be wearing sunglasses for a while :-)   To answer your question I have the file in Desktop and I'm using 'Run as a program'

I remember experiencing something like that a few weeks ago when I wrote a script to change wallpapers automatically. But I also then switched back to dark mode and the script worked (and it's still working). Try and switch back to dark mode, I think it should work, it might be something weird going on with the default configuration

Strange indeed - works for me now with the 'dark' file. Thanks for the help
